# Отключение всей музыки

Tags: swift

Можно как-то отключить в сцене сразу всю музыку?

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class Start: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var isPlaying = false
    var audioN: AVAudioPlayer!
//Кнопка 
 func buttonTap(sender:UIButton){
        if (sender.tag == 1){
            if isPlaying {
                isPlaying = false
                if (isPlaying == false){ 
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                })
            } else {
                isPlaying = true
                if (isPlaying == true){
                audioN = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PlayM", ofType: "mp3")!))
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                })
            }

        }
//И дальше мне эти звуки еще использовать нужно будет
func PlayGame(){
audioN.play()
}
```

Comment: какой класс воспроизводит музыку?

Comment: класс SKScene
`var audioN= try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PlayM", ofType: "mp3")!))`

Comment: я думаю `audioN.stop` может помочь

Comment: Маленько не то, дело в том, что музыка у меня включается с кнопки для проигрыша я пишу так : `audioN= try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PlayM", ofType: "mp3")!))` так что stop тут не подойдет

Comment: то есть вам надо, чтоб этот audioPlayer даже не создавался? создайте переменную musicEnabled, и если она false то даже и не создавайте плеер

Comment: А что для false прописать?
`if isPlaying {;
                isPlaying = false;
                musicEnabled = false;
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {;
                })   ;
            } else {;
                musicEnabled = true;
                if (musicEnabled == true){;
                audioТ = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ;NSURL(fileURLWithPath: ;NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PlayЬ", ofType: "mp3")!));
                };
                isPlaying = true;
                })
`

Comment: добавьте ка вы весь код, что у вас сейчас есть в вопрос, пока не закрыли

Comment: Добавила выше код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб остановить музыку, которая уже играет делвйте просто `audioN.stop()`

Чтобы не допустить запуск музыки, как я уже написал, вам надо сделать переменную, которая будет хранить включен ли сейчас звук и на основании этого запускать новые звуки

```
if(self.soundEnabled) {
    audioN.play()
}
```